# Возможен ли сделать такой возврат, к предыдущей странице?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня есть следующий код:
`<a href = "javascript:history.back()">Back to previous page</a>`
Он работает хорошо, но проблема в том что, у меня сайт-навигатор, то есть на странице где можно нажать на назад, есть также и другая страница, если человек кликнет на новую страницу, то при нажатии назад, он будет перемещен на ту страницу, на которую он нажал уже во второй раз, а мне нужно, чтобы он был перемещен на страницу, на которую он нажал первый раз, а все остальные разы, игнорировались.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/123106/

Comment: Проблема в том что, я перехожу на страницу с разных частей сайта, в одних случаях возвращение на предыдущую страницу должен быть одним, в другом случае другим.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков хз насколько корректный вариант, но..может хранить ключевую страницу в куках, а на ключевых страницах обновлять эту самую куку ?

Comment: @sousage1212 статья - описание апи, как именно реализовать - кучи способов, или пишите верную историю(добавлять через апи переходы на виртуальные страницы), либо сами рулите навигацией вешая хуки на переход назад\вперед а историю вести отдельно и у себя. Мой комментарий - направление куда копать, а не готовое решение.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я не тому отправил..и вы тоже xD

Comment: Проблема в чем? неверный переход назад? Хистори апи - решение всех проблем с кнопками навигации назад\вперед, именно с помощью данного апи можно настроить поведение своего приложения при нажатии кнопок назад\вперед.

Comment: Спасибо большое.  @ВладимирКлыков